# "missing glut32.dll" with OpenGL under VS2010

Tags: opengl

I'm using OpenGL under VS2010 doing a program for a long time. The program can always run independtly(I mean not run from vs2010 but double click out side of the IDE) until now. "missing glut32.dll" shows to make me put it under the same directory.

Some one may say that I may losing glut32.dll in system32(or in my case, syswow64 for 64 bit windows). It is proved true when I put it in the dir. The question is: I've never removed it before. How can it be that case?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`glut32.dll` is not a core system library. It's not installed there by default. Maybe some program's installer did put its own copy into the system directory and removed it on uninstallation.

Anyway, `glut32.dll` is not a standard library and as such it's not a bad thing to ship an independent copy with your own program.

Comment: Yeah, I think so, too. But my boss who always want to make a whole-independent exe pachage for publishing the program doesn't...thx:)

Comment: @Narusaki: Tell your boss, that if your program needs GLUT, you must ship it with GLUT. GLUT is not something you can expect to be present on the end user's system. In package based Linux distributions you can mark the GLUT package as a dependency, but for a self contained installer on Windows, not really. If everthing fails, link it statically with your program (you'll need FreeGLUT for this and build it as a static library first).

Answer (score 5):

You must put the glut.dll files in:

C:/Windows/SysWOW64
This is the folder where 32-bit .dlls are located.

C:/Windows/System32 contains the 64-bit .dlls. 
You can also put the GLUT.dlls in System32, if you want to feel safe.

Answer (score 1):

You could've just uninstalled something. I think it shouldn't be there in the first place, since it isn't some sort of standard library.

Anyway, it's always wise to supply all of the libraries needed by your program. You can have multiple applications using GLUT in different versions, so it's best bet to just keep it close to executable.

Comment: It's just because an independent executable program will always be welcome for some people...

Comment: Do as datenfolf said then, link statically. I don't really see the difference between copying one file or two files.

Answer (score 0):

Copy and paste the file `glut32.dil` in location `C:\Windows`,
it will fix all your problems.

If this does not work, then follow the steps below:

1. Go to settings->compiler->linker settings->add  `C:\MinGw\lib\glut32.lib` then PRESS ok.
2. Go to settings->compiler->Toolchain executables->`C:\Program Files (x86)\CodeBlocks\MinGW`
3. then copy and paste the file `glut32.dll` in location `C:\Windows`

Comment: From where please?

Answer (score 0):

In W10 (64b), glut32.dll is not installed as standard and the convention seems to be "go find the source and compile it" (assuming like me you have an aversion to getting it off generic dll download sites).

Eventually, after visiting https://opengl.org/resources/libraries/glut/ ,  I found http://vis.eng.uci.edu/~jkimball/eecs205/glut.html which has a link to the DLL at https://user.xmission.com/~nate/glut.html

Oddly, regsvr32 would not register it, but dropping it into c:\Windows\SysWOW64\ worked fine.

Not to be confused with glu32.dll which is already there.

Hope this helps. Pls don't be rude by downvoting without explanation or modifying my reply for brownie points. I am trying to do you a favour.